# WhatsApp web interface in Safari reloads because it is using "significant energy" how to fix?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, whatsapp.app, apple-silicon

I'm using Safari on a MacBook Air M1.

When I use web.whatsapp.com, it often reloads page with this error:

[image]

Is there an easy way to fix this?  Is Facebook running necessary processes that I can block somehow?

Comment: I’ve purged these comments as they appear unrelated to the problem. If you have a potential solution, please leave an answer that can be voted on.

Comment: Try enabling developer mode in Safari settings. I believe that will make it not reload automatically, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to fix this is to use a different browser. Both [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and [Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) shouldn't reload `web.whatsapp.com` or any other website without asking.

I do not have the latest Safari, but I dug through the latest [Safari user guide](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/safari/welcome/mac) and it seems there are no options in Safari's preferences to disable reloads due to significant energy consumption.

If you still **really** want to use Safari you might be able to find an extension that will stop these reload events, or you might be able to file a bug with WhatsApp and hopefully they will fix it soon. I do not recommend manually finding and blocking the guilty scripts from `web.whatsapp.com`. From my web development experience I can assure you that this will not be an easy task.